# How Do i Upload a 3gig XML File using FTP in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I have a 3 gig XML file that im uploading using FTP in c#
The way im doing it doesn't work
I get a error saying the stream closed...
and a 0 byte file When i do a smaller flie it works...
I need help :)

```
m_reset.Reset();
FtpClient conn = new FtpClient();
_LocalPath = LocalFilePath;
conn.Host = record.Attribute("ftpServer").Value.ToString();
conn.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(record.Attribute("ftpUser").Value.ToString(), record.Attribute("ftpPass").Value.ToString());
string fname = DateTime.Now.ToString("EnvisionPush-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_hh_mm_ss_tt}"+".xml");
conn.BeginOpenWrite(fname, new AsyncCallback(BeginOpenWriteCallback), conn);
m_reset.WaitOne();
conn.Disconnect();
```

```
static void BeginOpenWriteCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    FtpClient conn = ar.AsyncState as FtpClient;
    Stream istream = null, ostream = null;
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int read = 0;

    try {
        if (conn == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The FtpControlConnection object is null!");

        ostream = conn.EndOpenWrite(ar);
        istream = new FileStream(_LocalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        while ((read = istream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0) {
            ostream.Write(buf, 0, read);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (istream != null)
                istream.Close();

            if (ostream != null)
                ostream.Close();

            m_reset.Set();

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yea the error is a stream CLosed error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this [sample](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35902-create-an-ftp-class-library-in-c#/):

```
/// <summary>
/// Methods to upload file to FTP Server
/// </summary>
/// <param name="_FileName">local source file name</param>
/// <param name="_UploadPath">Upload FTP path including Host name</param>
/// <param name="_FTPUser">FTP login username</param>
/// <param name="_FTPPass">FTP login password</param>
public void UploadFile(string _FileName, string _UploadPath, string _FTPUser, string _FTPPass)
{
    System.IO.FileInfo _FileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(_FileName);

    // Create FtpWebRequest object from the Uri provided
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest _FtpWebRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(_UploadPath));

    // Provide the WebPermission Credintials
    _FtpWebRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(_FTPUser, _FTPPass);

    // By default KeepAlive is true, where the control connection is not closed
    // after a command is executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.KeepAlive = false;

    // set timeout for 20 seconds
    _FtpWebRequest.Timeout = 20000;

    // Specify the command to be executed.
    _FtpWebRequest.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

    // Specify the data transfer type.
    _FtpWebRequest.UseBinary = true;

    // Notify the server about the size of the uploaded file
    _FtpWebRequest.ContentLength = _FileInfo.Length;

    // The buffer size is set to 2kb
    int buffLength = 2048;
    byte[] buff = new byte[buffLength];

    // Opens a file stream (System.IO.FileStream) to read the file to be uploaded
    System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = _FileInfo.OpenRead();

    try
    {
        // Stream to which the file to be upload is written
        System.IO.Stream _Stream = _FtpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();

        // Read from the file stream 2kb at a time
        int contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);

        // Till Stream content ends
        while (contentLen != 0)
        {
            // Write Content from the file stream to the FTP Upload Stream
            _Stream.Write(buff, 0, contentLen);
            contentLen = _FileStream.Read(buff, 0, buffLength);
        }

        // Close the file stream and the Request Stream
        _Stream.Close();
        _Stream.Dispose();
        _FileStream.Close();
        _FileStream.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Upload Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to upload the 3gig file with a standard ftp client? It is possible that the server does not accept file of this size?